# What is "Interpolated Absolute Discounting" smoothing method

Tags: nltk

I'm asked to implement "Interpolated Absolute Discounting" for a bigram language model for a text. First, I don't know what is it exactly. I guess it is an interpolation between different ngrams (unigram, bigram, ), whose parameters needs to be learned

Second, what is the implemented probability distribution for this technique in `nltk` package?

Moreover, I must learn the parameters from a corpus. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It might be back to the [Kneser–Ney smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%E2%80%93Ney_smoothing) (which is used absolute discounting). And you can find it in Kneser-Ney probability distribution using the following code as an example (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40600190/3768871)):

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

gut_ngrams = ( ngram for sent in gutenberg.sents() for ngram in ngrams(sent, 3, pad_left = True, pad_right = True, right_pad_symbol='EOS', left_pad_symbol="BOS"))
freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(gut_ngrams)
kneser_ney = nltk.KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)
```